# How to select elements from Gridrow after Grid is refreshed using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, gridview

I have a grid where the column contents can be sorted in ascending/descending order by clicking on the row header - **sk_Total_Qty_Element**

To explain what the below code does it is just traversing the contents of one particular column - **jqTable_SK_Product/SK** row by row and printing the value in them.

Below code is giving me NoSuchElementException

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//thead/tr/th[@id='jqTable_SK_Total Qty']")
WebElement sk_Total_Qty_Element;

public void warehousingGridTotalQtyClick() throws Exception {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    ldriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(ldriver, 100);
    WebElement housingTotalQtyElement = wait1
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(sk_Total_Qty_Element));
    housingTotalQtyElement.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    wait1 = new WebDriverWait(ldriver, 100);
    housingTotalQtyElement = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(sk_Total_Qty_Element));
    housingTotalQtyElement.click();

    WebElement grid = ldriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']"));
    System.out.println(grid.getTagName());

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    List<WebElement> skList = grid.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@aria-describedby='jqTable_SK_Product/SK']"));

    for (WebElement sk : skList) {
        System.out.println(sk.getText());
    }

}
```

but when I do sort the grid view in descending order I'm getting below error:

> FAILED: housingGrid_TC003
> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']"}
> (Session info: headless chrome=100.0.4896.88)

But when I don't do the grid sorting in descending order i.e., when I remove the below piece of code from above which basically double clicks the row header - **sk_Total_Qty_Element** the code runs perfectly well.

```
        WebElement housingTotalQtyElement = wait1
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(sk_Total_Qty_Element));
    housingTotalQtyElement.click();
    Thread.sleep(200);
    wait1 = new WebDriverWait(ldriver, 100);
    housingTotalQtyElement = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(sk_Total_Qty_Element));
    housingTotalQtyElement.click();
```

To overcome this error I have tried to focus on the by using window handles but that did not work out and also I tried using **WebDriverWait** with below code and that did not work either leading to similar error

```
WebElement grid = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']")));

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']"}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create `WebDriverWait` object every time like you've done it above:

```
new WebDriverWait(ldriver, 100);
```

Just create once and use the reference at multiple places.

Since you are clicking twice `housingTotalQtyElement` on this column with just `.2` sec gap, I'd say increase this time to at least `2 seconds`

so

```
Thread.sleep(200);
```

should be:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Also, instead of having just `findElement` like below

```
WebElement grid = ldriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']"));
```

use `WebDriverWait`

```
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']"))).click();
```

Comment: As suggested have tried below code
WebElement grid = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']")));

Got again similar error:

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']"}

Please help

Comment: That's strange it should have been resulted in timeout exception, also did you try to increase the hardcoded delay like 2 secs or 3, or even 5 before interaction?

Comment: I took your cue added Thread.sleep(10000); but that did not make any difference.

Comment: okay can you inspect the element in automation window, see if we have any entry by this xpath `//div[@id='gview_jqTable_SK']` ?

Comment: Yes I could see it, I did exactly that.

Comment: any iframe involved?

Comment: Could you please join now for the conversation, thank you

Comment: Is this resolved? Sorry I couldn't follow up.

Comment: The problem is still there. Is there a possibility to connect with you to resolve this issue. Please